# Why does the chart on a coin vary between exchanges?

Tags: exchanges, charts

Look at the BCH chart for instance, the 8 november there is a wild selloff following the cancelation of the new scaling protocol for bitcoin. This has nothign to do with BCH but causes a selloff nevertheless, on big volume with  a long deep red candle. This is on Bitfinex. Then look atr the same
chart at Kraken. No long deep red candle, no selloff.

So I guess either the chart was edited (manipulated) afterwards, or no Kraken customers sold any BCH outside that range on the chart?

Answer (score 1):

There is no central market for the bitcoin or other altcoins.

Crypto currencies are exchanged on each exchange for the price set by people transacting there. This means that the price is set exchange by exchange, not centrally for every coin.

Thus the variance of the graphs.

Cheers, David

Comment: So in theory and maybe in some strange situations, the price for a  coin may go in totally seperate directions on different exchanges, if the people transacting in different countries for instance, have radically different views of (future) value .. has this ever happened?

Comment: I guess people would buy at the cheap exchange and then move the coin to the expensive one to sell it there, so the price would go up at the cheap exchange until a relative equilibrium was restored  between exchanges ... lol :) its funny stuff ..

Comment: @achrp That is exactly it. For instance, in China the price of crypto currencies is typically higher, as there is an increased demand. This happens in other countries too, where the fiat currency is unreliable or cannot be taken out of the country.